# jQuery slider buttons api methods

Tags: jquery, api, slider, wordpress

I have set up a jQuery slider in wordpress and the plug in comes with a api. I'm trying to create my own previous and next buttons can someone help me with what the code would be for that

Here is the api info that is given to me

API Methods:
Previous Slide: revapi1.revprev();
Next Slide: revapi1.revnext();

I guess I need to know how to use those two methods above

Thanks
Jamie

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this.

Place this in your header:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#revNext").click(function() {
        revapi1.revnext();  
    });
});
```

Place this in your body

```
<div id="revNext"> Next Slide </div>
```